# MySQL Trigger with conditional statement and update another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, delimiter, conditional-statements

On MySQL 5.5, I am trying to write a trigger to do the following:

- Checks a condition for the insert (is group_id between 8-20?)
- If the condition is true, then update the user with the same user_id on **another table**, called phpbb_users.
- The update on this other table is to set user_rank to NEW.group_id from the insert on the table that has the trigger.
- Else, do nothing.

**Not experienced at all, and stuck.** It's not working when I run the query. Here is what I've got so far.

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_rank AFTER INSERT ON `phpbb_user_group`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.group_id BETWEEN 8 AND 20) THEN
            UPDATE phpbb_users
            SET user_rank=NEW.group_id 
            WHERE user_id=NEW.user_id;
       ELSE 
            UPDATE phpbb_users
            SET user_rank='0'
            WHERE user_id=NEW.user_id;
       END IF;
    END$$;

DELIMITER;
```

(Note, the "else" clause is unnecessary really - happy for any suggestions for improvement of this code!)

Comment: What is your question?  Are you having a problem with this code?

Comment: you could use `user_rank=IF(NEW.group_id BETWEEN 8 AND 20,NEW.group_id,0)`

Comment: Yes, it's not executing on the database. I am very inexperienced and I can't work out what's wrong with it.

Comment: The `;` after `END$$` looks incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to get rid of the `else` try

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_rank AFTER INSERT ON `phpbb_user_group`
FOR EACH ROW 
   UPDATE phpbb_users
   SET user_rank=IF(NEW.group_id BETWEEN 8 AND 20,NEW.group_id,"0")
   WHERE user_id=NEW.user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, great tip! That's much better syntax. But it is not working when I run it in the console. I get error message "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER upd_rank AFTER INSERT ON `phpbb_user_group`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   UPDA' at line 1"  I can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: ok, removed it. I am in Navicat and now, when I run this, I simply get an arrow like this ->   (no error msg!) Does that mean all is fine?

Comment: A row starting with `->` means that the current statement hasn't finished yet. MySQL is waiting for the DELIMITER - did you change it? In my case it's not needced to change it. I don't know NaviCat so you have to test it by inserting something into phpbb_user_group.

Comment: Hi @Hanna if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.